# Use of Banker's Algorithm

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, bankers-algorithm

Why we need banker's algorithm when we have locks,completion variables and semaphores.Since locks are acquired in linux in definite order,there can't be any deadlocks.So what is the use of running banker's algorithm in such situation.

Comment: "Since locks are acquired in linux in definite order,there can't be any deadlocks". No? How would Linux know if your code is written well enough to avoid deadlocks? And inside Linux...there too is no magic, only human written source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Banker algorithm** is used to **avoid deadlock** by checking whether a resource allocation may cause the system to be deadlock or not, while the **lock** is used to solve the **critical section problem**, i.e., to avoid more than one process can enter the critical section at the same time.

Locking itself cannot avoid/prevent deadlock without combining with other deadlock solutions.

And as **deviantfan's** comment: no restriction on the lock acquisition in most of the OSs. The following is a simple example in which the system may be deadlock even the use of lock is valid:

P1: ....; lock(fileA);  lock(fileB); .... unlock(fileA);  unlock(fileB); ....

P2: ....; lock(fileB);  lock(fileA);..... unlock(fileB);  unlock(fileA); ....

Comment: Since resources are represented as files in linux, cant we treat allocation of a resource to a process as The process is using the critical section(file of that resource)

Comment: And who manages the locking of the files? Right... (and altough it´s said everything in Linux is a file, it´s not that "everything". Not every variable thing in the kernel needs to be a file...)

Comment: File is just an example of the shared resource. The file locks are monitored by the OS.

Comment: @Prashant: Why not? Critical section is a segment of code that modify the shared resource. You can find this in the Reader-Writer problem in most of the OS books.

Comment: @PrashantSinghRathore Please note the difference is about exclusively acquiring one resource (lock) vs safely acquiring multiple resources(lock mechanism along might result dead-lock situation).